# Get the alphanumeric month value for a timezone enabled DateTime instance

Tags: java, datetime, time, timezone, dst

I have a linux server which is set to use UTC time as it is based in the UK. I have a piece of java code which runs at the New York time of 22:00 on the last day of June. This means in the UK, it would be the next day of the next month.

I want to retrieve the alphanumeric month (January, February, etc) from the DateTime instance, but for the America/New_York date. Currently, the below code gives me the UK month of July, but I want it to give me June as the DateTime is set to America/New_York.

```
DateFormat fullMonthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();
dt1 = dt1.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(fullMonthFormat.format(dt1.toDate()));
```

For example. If i was to run this on 30/06/2016 22:00 New York time, the println statement will give me the value 'July'. How can I obtain the correct month text, which should be June?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)) into fullMonthFormat, since you want the month of New York.
The DateFormat is using the local time (UTC) if you want to format any date to a specific Time Zone you need to set that particular Time Zone to the DateFormat object.

So it should look like this:

```
DateFormat fullMonthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();
DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
dt1 = dt1.withZone(dtz);
fullMonthFormat.setTimeZone(dtz.toTimeZone());
System.out.println(fullMonthFormat.format(dt1.toDate()));
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggesstion. I used the below code as im using DateTimeZone to set the timezone on the DateTime instances before i come to produce the alphanumeric day of month..


'fullMonthFormat.setTimeZone(dt1.getZone().toTimeZone());'

Answer (score 2):

## UTC is *not* UK time

Servers should generally be set to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) regardless of their physical location. But never depend on the server’s assigned time zone. Always specify any optional time zone, as seen in code below. (ditto for `Locale` by the way)

Also, do not conflate [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with [time in the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_Kingdom). UK time has anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). Think of UTC as “world time”.

## java.time

You are using old outmoded classes. The date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them.

The [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). These classes were inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. Much of the java.time functionality is [back-ported to Jave 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further [adapted to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### Time zones

We must track time zones. The [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) class represents a time zone (an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) *plus* rules for handling anomalies such as DST). Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), *never* the 3-4 letter codes seen commonly in mainstream media such as `EST`.

```
ZoneId zoneId_New_York = ZoneId.of ( "America/New_York" );
ZoneId zoneId_London = ZoneId.of ( "Europe/London" );
```

### New York zone

The [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class represents a moment on the timeline with a resolution of nanoseconds and with a [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) for an assigned time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt_NewYork = ZonedDateTime.of ( 2016 , 6 , 30 , 22 , 0 , 0 , 0 , zoneId_New_York );
```

The [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) represents each month of the year.

```
Month month_NewYork = Month.from ( zdt_NewYork );
```

The `Month` enum offers handy methods such as telling you the month number (1-12).

```
int month_NewYork_number = month_NewYork.getValue (); // 1-12 January-December.
```

The [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum can even localize the name of the month by human language and cultural norms described by a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). Here I use the [locale of Québec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#CANADA_FRENCH) to generate French values just to make clear the behavior, but in your particular case would likely use [`Locale.UK`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#UK) or [`Locale.US`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US).

```
String month_NewYork_name = month_NewYork.getDisplayName ( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

Dump console. Notice the month name of `juin` (French for 'June') and month # 6.

```
System.out.println ( "zdt_NewYork: " + zdt_NewYork + " | month #: " + month_NewYork_number + " | name: " + month_NewYork_name );
```

> zdt_NewYork: 2016-06-30T22:00-04:00[America/New_York] | month #: 6 | name: juin

## London zone

Next we adjust that `ZonedDateTime` into another time zone. The java.time classes use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), so we actually generate a fresh distinct object rather than changing/editing (“mutating”) the original object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt_London = zdt_NewYork.withZoneSameInstant ( zoneId_London );
Month month_London = Month.from ( zdt_London );
int month_London_number = month_London.getValue (); // 1-12 January-December.
String month_London_name = month_London.getDisplayName ( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

Dump to console. Notice the output of `juillet` (French for 'July'), and month # 7.

```
System.out.println ( "zdt_London: " + zdt_London + " | month #: " + month_London_number + " | name: " + month_London_name );
```

> zdt_London: 2016-07-01T03:00+01:00[Europe/London] | month #: 7 | name: juillet

### UTC zone

Lastly, we check the UTC value. An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents a moment on the timeline always in UTC. An `Instant` object can be extracted from any `ZonedDateTime` object. The `Instant` class is the basic building block of other classes ([`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) and `ZonedDateTime`).

```
Instant instant = zdt_London.toInstant ();
```

Dump to console. Notice the output is *not* the same as London time. London in the summer suffers from DST while UTC remains steady. So we see 2 AM here for UTC rather than 3 AM above for `Europe/London`.

```
System.out.println ( "UTC… instant: " + instant );
```

> UTC… instant: 2016-07-01T02:00:00Z

Keep in mind that all three of these date-time values (zdt_NewYork, zdt_London, and instant) all represent the **very same simultaneous point on the timeline**, the very same moment in history. Each is the same moment but viewed through the lens of various wall-clock times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.util.Date` as well to achieve that like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
Date datetime = new Date();
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(datetime));
```

Hope this helps.